# How to register 2 consumers to same queue in Masstransit and RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have requirement, where multiple consumers are attached to one queue. So as soon as messages receive in that queue both consumers can process in a distributed way. Like if there are 10 messages, then Consumer1 will receive some messages and Consumer 2 will receive remaining messages. How to achieve this using Masstransit and RabbitMQ.

Thanks

I tried 2 consumer for one queue but messages are duplicating. Like message number 1 is processing by both the consumers.

Comment: If you are scaling out multiple instances of your consumer service on the same queue, the consumers will load balance. It sounds like you're actually configuring two separate consumers on the same receive endpoint on the same bus instance? If so, yes, both consumers get a copy of each message.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPatterson for reply. Yes I am using one bus and register 2 consumers like below               
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("my_queue", e =>
                {
                    e.Consumer<CustomerConsumer1>(cc => cc.UseConcurrencyLimit(1));
                    e.Consumer<CustomerConsumer1>(cc => cc.UseConcurrencyLimit(1));
                });
         
            await busControl.StartAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            await Task.Run(() => Console.ReadKey()); . Please provide any sample code to do this.

Comment: Sorry, that isn't how MassTransit or Stack Overflow works.